# Capture text input and save it , dialogflow inline editor

Tags: editor, inline, dialogflow-es

I have created a chatbot with dialogflow using the inline editor. It works perfect right now.

My problem is, how to capture the message entered by the user? ie:

Imagine I have this conversation:

```
user: Good morning
bot: Hi, how can I help you...
```

mu purpose is to get the text:

```
Good morning.
```

Then, I'll store this statement into my database.

I want just a method to capture it.  Can you tell me what I should write, please?

**Example:** if I want to capture a parameter , I write:

```
let ville = agent.parameters.ville;
```

In case of the whole text, what should I write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the full content of the message the user said, use:
let query = agent.query